# Ionic + Phonegap Build app : facebook and google login, using native apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, single-sign-on, phonegap-build

Can someone point me to a plugin or a code snippet to implement both Facebook and Google login in my Ionic + Phonegap Build app ?

It must also work as a pure webapp (in a desktop browser).

I would like this feature to be able to log from the native facebook or google+ apps that the user has already installed on his device, so he doesn't need to retype his id+password. But, if these apps are not installed, the code must fallback on the normal login process.

My app communicate with a cloudant database using pouchDB in case you need this information.

(I have to use Phonegap Build because I don't work on a mac).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook:

```
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/
```

Google login:

```
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/implementing_google_login_in_a_phonegap_app
```

Try these two links ,it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Arun, will this work if the app is used as a pure web app in a desktop browser ?

Comment: Is there a tutorial somewhere to work with these plugins and also code for the browser only option ?